# Depends on virtual package?

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia

I'm trying to install old legacy drivers (Nvidia 304):

```bash
sudo apt install nvidia-legacy-304xx-driver
```

```bash
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 glx-alternative-nvidia : Breaks: nvidia-legacy-304xx-alternative (< 304.137-7~) but 304.137-5~deb9u1 is to be installed
                          Breaks: nvidia-legacy-304xx-driver (< 304.137-7~) but 304.137-5~deb9u1 is to be installed
 nvidia-legacy-304xx-driver : Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-legacy-304xx (= 304.137-5~deb9u1) but it is not installable
                              Depends: nvidia-legacy-304xx-kernel-dkms (= 304.137-5~deb9u1) but it is not installable or
                                       nvidia-legacy-304xx-kernel-304.137
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**OK...**

```bash
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-legacy-304xx nvidia-legacy-304xx-kernel-dkms -y
```

...

```bash
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 glx-alternative-nvidia : Breaks: nvidia-legacy-304xx-alternative (< 304.137-7~) but 304.137-5~deb9u1 is to be installed
                          Breaks: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-legacy-304xx (< 304.137-7~) but 304.137-5~deb9u1 is to be installed
 nvidia-kernel-common : Breaks: nvidia-legacy-304xx-kernel-support (< 305) but 304.137-5~deb9u1 is to be installed
 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-legacy-304xx : Depends: xorg-video-abi-23 or
                                                   xorg-video-abi-20 but it is not installable or
                                                   xorg-video-abi-19 but it is not installable or
                                                   xorg-video-abi-18 but it is not installable or
                                                   xorg-video-abi-15 but it is not installable or
                                                   xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                                                   xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                                                   xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                                                   xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                                                   xorg-video-abi-10 but it is not installable or
                                                   xorg-video-abi-8 but it is not installable or
                                                   xorg-video-abi-6.0 but it is not installable
                                          Depends: xserver-xorg-core (< 2:1.19.99) but 2:21.1.4-3 is to be installed
                                          Recommends: nvidia-legacy-304xx-driver (>= 304.137) but it is not installable
                                          Recommends: nvidia-legacy-304xx-vdpau-driver (>= 304.137) but it is not going to be installed
                                          Recommends: nvidia-settings-legacy-304xx but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**OKAY...**

```bash
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken xorg-video-abi-23 xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-legacy-304xx nvidia-legacy-304xx-kernel-dkms -y
```

```bash
Package xorg-video-abi-23 is a virtual package provided by:
  xserver-xorg-core 2:1.19.2-1+deb9u5 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'xorg-video-abi-23' has no installation candidate
```

Last hope

```bash
sudo apt purge "*nvidia*"
sudo apt autoremove
sudo restart now
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken xorg-video-abi-23 xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-legacy-304xx nvidia-legacy-304xx-kernel-dkms -y
```

Nothing...

What I'm doing wrong?

**OS**: Debian 11.5.0

**/etc/apt/sources.list**:

```bash
# deb cdrom:[Official Debian GNU/Linux Live 11.5.0 gnome 2022-09-10T11:47]/ bullseye main

deb cdrom:[Official Debian GNU/Linux Live 11.5.0 gnome 2022-09-10T11:47]/ bullseye main

# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
#deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main
# Line commented out by installer because it failed to verify:
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ buster-updates main contrib non-free

# Debian Sid (Nvidia 340 legacy)
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free

# Debian 9 "Stretch" (Nvidia 304 legacy)
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [the 304xx drivers don’t support releases of X.org after the version used in Debian 9](https://bugs.debian.org/995173); there is no way of installing them on Debian 10 or later without performing major surgery on your distribution.

[The 340xx drivers aren’t available in Debian 11 or later either](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=973599); they are maintained in Debian unstable so that the Debian 10 packages can be updated, but those packages aren’t usable on Debian 11.

Note that [you should never add a “sid” line to your `sources.list`](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) when you’re using a Debian release other than unstable.